# Обезопасить токен

Tags: java, token, discord-api

Написал Discord-бота на Java. Протестировал, но в какой-то момент мой токен перехватили и мой канал взломали и удалили все. Есть ли способ обезопасить токен от перехвата? Или надо что-то другое делать?

Если можно обезопасить - то как? Токен у меня был вписан в программе (Наверное, поэтому так все и произошло)

Comment: Может быть Вы сами свой токен выложили в открытый доступ? В гит например.

Comment: Во-первых, непоказывание токена никому (кроме Discord API) должно полностью защитить его от перехвата. Во-вторых, нужно для начала разобраться, как именно его перехватили-то. Вы с кем-то поделились программой со вшитым токеном? Ну вот не надо было так делать, держите токен только у себя

Comment: @AndreyPopov Вот... на гит выставил... А еще как-то могут перехватить токен? Допустим, прослушка сети? Или я брежу

Comment: @Antonio112009 
>Вот... на гит выставил... 
Это скорей всего и была причина. Все остальные варианты это больше похоже на параною.